# How to integrate social-auth in my project

Tags: django

I want to use social-auth to provide registration/authentication via social network sites. I have been trying to understand how to use [social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth), but I have been unable to get beyond installing dependencies and configuring backends.

I am basically new to Django and I have tried hard to understand before posting on the forum. Maybe because I am not very familiar with it that is why I have been unsuccessful. Can anybody please point me to a tutorial on how to use social-auth. This will also help me in integrating other apps.

**Update:**

Although the answer given below solved my problem, I just want to share that I ended up using [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) instead of social-auth. And the latest version of django-allauth appears to be the best Django authentication app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's somehow unclear from documentation.

You need to create apps in Twitter/Facebook/whatever you want to use.

- If you want twitter see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
- If you want facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

They will give you api key and api secret.

Follow these basic steps that refer to socialauth docs:

1. pip install
2. add social-auth to installed apps
3. copy AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS
4. fill api key and api secret
5. add social auth url patterns
6. configure authentication and association complete URL names (SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME)
7. context processor
8. syncdb

Now, what the documentation doesn't tell you, is to put links in your login template:

```
Login with <a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'twitter' %}">Twitter</a>
```

Should work.

Comment: I have done all the things that you pointed out. Now when I made the login page and added the line you asked me to I get the following error

Reverse for 'complete' with arguments '(u'twitter',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Can you tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry, I forgot one step: add SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME  = 'socialauth_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete' to your code

Comment: Actually as it was given in their specification I was using SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME = 'complete' and this was causing a problem. Now the thing is my page seems to process when I, say, use /login/twitter but then it redirects to login-error page can you tell me why is that? Is it because I am using the local host server?
Please help

Comment: It's hard to debug program over comments, but suspect bad api or secret. Also, remember to fill Callback URL field in Twitter application settings. It's mandatory for web apps (does not matter what you put in there, as long as it's not empty).

Comment: Thanks for the advise I had not filled the callback url I thought it was not mandatory... Now it seems to be working. Could you tell me how I could create a native registration using social-auth and not a social registration

Comment: In these steps, where does one "fill api key and api secret"?  I'm pretty much brand new to Django and this framework, so I'm really sorry if it's something very obvious.

Comment: @Weaver, if you go to the FB or Twitter new app links in Tomek's post above, they will issue you with the API keys, then  as per the social-auth docs, you'll need to add those vars to your settings.py file, as so:  `TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY         = ''  
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET  = ''  
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = ''  
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = ''`