# How to connect account with facebook? (login via facebook)

Tags: django

How to connect account with facebook? (login via facebook) using django-social-auth or other?
Please a very simple example. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate social-auth in my project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867300/how-to-integrate-social-auth-in-my-project)

Answer (score 1):

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530277/how-to-make-facebook-login-possible-in-django-app) for facebook

and for all social login like gmail, facebook, twitter.. ect look [here](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/08/django-socialauth-login-via-twitter-facebook-openi/), i prefer to use it

and [this](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/facebook-authentication/) may be use full